# Will delete command clear the memory allocated with new?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand how delete clears the memory allocated for an object.
Can anybody please explain it clearly?

I'm doing something like this:

```
class MyClass{
public :
    MyClass() {std::cout <<" constructed\n";}
    ~MyClass() {std::cout <<" destroyed\n";} 
};
int main () 
{
    MyClass * pt=NULL;
    pt = new MyClass();
    delete pt;
    if ( pt == NULL ) 
        std::cout<<"deallocated\n";
}
```

Comment: What exactly is unclear? `delete pt` destroys the `MyClass` object (calling its destructor) and frees the memory it occupied. It doesn't modify the pointer `pt`, which is left "dangling", with an invalid value.

Comment: If pt won't be destroyed due to scope, you need to explicitly assign it NULL.  Then again, the "new" way to do this is use smart_pointer, shared_pointer, etc., and not have to deal with it.

Comment: The "memory allocated" is usually not cleared, at least not by the free call. It may or may not become unaccessible (but often you can just -- for test purposes -- access it and see what's there). No magic involved. The only thing that happens is that the next allocation may use the freed memory.

Answer (score 11):

`delete pt` will call the *destructor* `~MyClass()`, then release any memory occupied by the object `*pt` back to the operating system.

What it *doesn't* do is change the value of the pointer, as that's unnecessary.

Some programmers will set `pt = nullptr` after a `delete` since the C++ standard guarantees that `delete nullptr` is a no-op. So it can help program stability.

Comment: `delete pt, pt = nullptr;`, the only instance where I put multiple instructions in one line

Comment: However, you have to be aware of the tradeoff that you can't detect multiple frees if you set the pointer to null, so that kind of bug would be hard to find. Of course we're not doing a lot of raw `new` and `delete` in actual code, are we?

Comment: @coyotte508 (/cc bathsheba) setting to null after free is not a good idea. If you access the pointer after the `delete`, it's most likely a logic error, and you don't want to hide it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I agree in most cases but setting to `null` *might* just save the day, say, if your codebase finds itself in the read-only memory chip of a Mars lander or whatnot. That said, I absolutely resist using `delete` explicitly but rely on the shared and unique pointer classes. Mainly so I don't wake up in the middle of the night in a panic.

Comment: @chris One "error" might be hidden, but the other one where a deleted pointer is accessed (maybe just after a free) will be detected instead with a resounding SIGSEV and a nice call stack, and this kind of error is, in my opinion, more serious.

Comment: @coyotte508, Of course, it's a tradeoff. I would probably trust accessing a null pointer more than accessing a freed pointer, too. I guess I don't really have to make a choice here because I stick to smart pointers etc.

Answer (score 2):

`delete p` does indeed deallocate the storage occupied by the object pointed to by the value of `p`, among other things.

It does *not* modify the value of `p`, though. That wouldn't make sense. consider this:

```
int * funky_ptr();

delete funky_ptr();
```

Here the operand of `delete` is a prvalue; what sense would there be in modifying it?

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

On debug builds, some compilers will usually clear out the memory (either set everything to `0` or some bit pattern that can be used to identity clears later) in order to help debugging.

That way, accessing a deleted object will more likely yield an access violation early on, rather than it failing silently.

On release builds, other than the (pseudo-)destructor being called, nothing else happens.

Note that setting pointers to `NULL` after `delete` or `free` is a code smell, as it can mask some bugs.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to understand how delete clears the memory allocated for an object. can anybody please make it clear?

`delete` delete does the following:

- look at the received address, and interpret it as a pointer (to data specified by the pointer type)
- call the destructor(s) for all instances of data, for objects at the received address
- tell the internal memory allocation subsystem, that the address in the received pointer, is now free. This will either release the memory to the operating system (so other applications can use it) or (more likely) cache it internally and use it for subsequent allocations (the next allocation performed using `new` or `new[]` with same or smaller size may receive this pointer).

These are the minimal steps to deallocate heap data in C++.

You will notice that nowhere in that list is a "set pointer to null/zero/speciffic value". This is because there are cases when the value of the pointer, is not interesting after the delete statement (such as, within a destructor body), and setting it to zero would just waste processor cycles.

As a rule of thumb, in C++ code is written so you do not pay for what you do not use. If you have use for such functionality, it is trivial to write it yourself (this example won't work for arrays):

```
template<typename T>
void safe_delete(T*& ptr) // use instead of delete
{
    delete ptr;
    ptr = nullptr;
}
```